# What is the difference between infinite product and regularized product?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, divergent-series, zeta-functions

For a sequence of non-zero complex numbers $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \cdots$, the infinite product is defined by
$$
\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\lambda_{n} := \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{i}\lambda_{n}$$
to be the limit of partial product.

For the same sequence $(\lambda_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, we define the zeta-regularized product by
$$
\widehat{\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}\lambda_{n} := \exp(-\zeta_{\lambda}^{'}(0)),
$$
where $\zeta_{\lambda}(s)$ is the zeta function which is given by
$$
\zeta_{\lambda}(s)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\lambda_{n}^{-s}.
$$
We assume that the zeta function has an analytical continuation up to $0$.

My first question is:

> What is the difference between the two products?

For more a precise question, I add an example.

For example, if we consider the sequence $(n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, we have two different results: for the infinite product, we have
$$
\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}n = \infty;
$$
while for the zeta-regularized product we have
$$
\widehat{\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}n=\sqrt{2\pi}.
$$
This results imply that, even for a same sequence, the zeta-regularized product could be convergent while the infinite product is not.
(Under the condition that the zeta function for the sequence is well-defined.)

This example leads to my second question:

> If an infinite product is convergent, then does it coincide with the zeta-regularized product?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: You probably want to rule out the possibility $\lambda_n=0$.